# Связь ядра приложения Android с интерфейсом

Tags: java, android, ui

Только начал работать с Android и сразу наткнулся на проблему:
как управлять элементами UI из других классов?

Пример, у меня есть класс (на самом деле тупой свич), который в зависимости от приходящих в него данных должен выполнять различные действия (добавить элемент в ListView, выдать уведомление и т.д.) как сделать так, чтобы можно было управлять элементами активности из него, и разумно ли это?

Если нет, подскажите, пожалуйста, каким методом работать с интерфейсом.

Comment: знакомы с паттернами MVP, MVVM, MVC?

Comment: не очень, и как я понимаю, самое время начинать изучать...

Comment: а еще освоить поиск. попробуйте поискать: архитектура андроид приложения.

Comment: Оу, как заумно, общятся с ядром:) http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/ с него начинал, хорошо познакомитесь с ui, с основами, теже List. А так не ясен вопрос...

Comment: в андроид классическая схема - взаимодействие с активити строится, как правило, на колбэках (методах обратного вызова). При определенном событии класс шлет колбэк, активити, подписанная на этот колбэк принимает его и взаимодействует с UI. Как пример, работа слушателей касаний на кнопки (колбэк OnClickListener)